# How to display gray scale 8 bit raw pixel data array (i.e. byte[]) to Image control in WinUI3

Tags: c#, bitmap, winui-3, winui

The raw pixel data array (byte[]) is retreived from camera and it is notified as an event to main page.
The pixel format is like that:-

- GrayScale 8bit (i.e color band = 1)
- width: 612, height: 512 -> total size = 612 * 512 = 313,344 bytes

Here is my code so far, which does not show anything in image control.

```
// Behind code of Main Page //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// This event is called when camera image was captured from camera library
private void Camera_ImageCaptured(object? sender, ImageCapturedEventArgs e)
{
    // CameraImage is Image control of the main page
    _ = CameraImage.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(async () =>
    {
        await GetBitmapAsync3(e.ImageBuffer, e.Width, e.Height);
    });
}

// This method is called in UI thread
public async Task GetBitmapAsync3(byte[] data, int width, int height)
{
    WriteableBitmap newImage = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
    using var stream = newImage.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
    stream.Write(data);
    await stream.FlushAsync();
    stream.Close();
    ViewModel.WriteableBitmap = newImage;
}

// parameters from camera library
public class ImageCapturedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ImageCapturedEventArgs( byte[] buffer, int width, int height );

    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageBuffer { get; set; }
}
```

```
// View Model ///////////////////////////////////////////////
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap;
    public int ImageWidth{ get; set; }
    public int ImageHeight { get; set; }
    public int ImageSize => ImageWidth * ImageHeight;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ImageWidth = 612;
        ImageHeight = 512;

        writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(ImageWidth, ImageHeight);
    }
}
```

// XAML of main page /////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:MainViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid x:Name="ContentArea">
    <Image
        x:Name="CameraImage"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Width="612"
        Height="512"
        Source="{Binding WriteableBitmap}" />
</Grid>
```

I tried it with the above code, but it does not show anything in main page...
Does anyone help me?

Comment: That cannot work w/o converting bitmap somehow. Can you post a sample (that we can recognize...) image of these 313344 bytes somewhere? Also do you really have a byte[] as input or is it a pointer to unmanaged memory interopped in lower layers?

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you for you comment. Yes, I have the byte[] that the size is really 313344 bytes. I would upload the bin file that recorded the data, if there is the way to attach the file to this thread.. but not sure...

Comment: Upload it anywhere and put the link in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap` supports 1 byte data for each pixel.

Can you try the next?

```cs
public async Task GetBitmapAsync3(byte[] data, int width, int height)
{
    byte[] outputData= new byte[width * height * 4];
    int inputIndex = 0;
    int outputIndex = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            byte value = data[inputIndex++];
            outputData[outputIndex++] = value;
            outputData[outputIndex++] = value;
            outputData[outputIndex++] = value;
            outputData[outputIndex++] = 255;
        }
    }


    WriteableBitmap newImage = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
    using var stream = newImage.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
    await stream.WriteAsync(outputData);
    await stream.FlushAsync();
    stream.Close();
    ViewModel.WriteableBitmap = newImage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me the code. I tried it and was able to see the image data! but it seems that my code have performance issue because displaying speed was not fast.. when I put my hand at the front of the camera, the image data was updated after 10 secondes approximately. And I feel like the image looks a little bit darker than I expected...

Comment: A @György Kőszeg commented, reusing the `WriteableBitmap` should help. Avoiding unnecessary code in the UI thread should also help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing#self-allocating-vs-preallocated-buffers) library to interpret a byte array as a bitmap data (disclaimer: I am the author).

Use the technology-agnostic [core package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing.Core) to treat your array as an 8-bit grayscale bitmap:

```cs
using KGySoft.Drawing.Imaging;

// ...

// interpreting the byte array as a grayscale bitmap
var myArrayBackedBitmap = BitmapDataFactory.CreateBitmapData(myByteArray,
   new Size(612, 512),
   stride: 612,
   pixelFormat: KnownPixelFormat.Format8bppGrayScale);

// now you can Get/Set pixels, draw other images into your bitmap, etc.
```

And if you use the [WinUI 3 specific package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing.WinUI) you can simply convert the managed bitmap to a WinUI 3 `WriteableBitmap`:

```cs
var myWinUI3Bitmap = await myArrayBackedBitmap.ToWriteableBitmapAsync();
```

**Perfomance considerations:**

Please note that [`ToWriteableBitmapAsync`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_WinUI_ReadableBitmapDataExtensions_ToWriteableBitmapAsync_1.htm) always creates a new `WriteableBitmap` instance, which may affect performance as it's neither disposable nor managed (as almost everything in WinUI, it is a "remote" COM object). It could be better to re-use a single `WriteableBitmap` instance:

```cs
// A field allocated once
private WriteableBitmap _renderingTarget;

// [...]

// instead of ToWriteableBitmap, just draw the grayscale bitmap always into the same bitmap.
using (var targetBitmapData = _renderingTarget.GetReadWriteBitmapData())
    await myArrayBackedBitmap.DrawIntoAsync(_renderingTarget);

// Here, after the end of using block the target WriteableBitmap is
// invalidated so the possible bindings can refresh themselves
```

Feel free to check out also [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing/tree/master/Examples/WinUI) WinUI specific example for the library.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The one thing I am concerning is the license of the library. Is it MIT or not? I can not use the library unless the license is MIT.

Comment: The MIT license does not prohibit you to use other permissive licenses. And if you reference the binaries only (eg. the NuGet package) you have no obligation whatsoever (not even mentioning my license) so it will not conflict with MIT. But even if you would re-use my sources from the library the only thing you need to do is giving attribution (ie. indicate the source in any reasonable way, eg, as a comment in the source code). My license prohibits only one thing: distributing a modified source as yours.